# Weakened conditions for étale + X implies faithfully flat.

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $F:R \to S$ be an étale morphism of rings.  It follows with some work that $f$ is flat.

However, faithful flatness is another story.  It's not hard to show that faithful + flat is weaker than being faithfully flat.  An equivalent condition to being faithfully flat is being surjective on spectra.

The question:
Is there any further condition we can require on an étale morphism that implies faithful flatness?

"Faithfully flat implies faithfully flat" or "surjective on spectra is equivalent to faithfully flat" do not count.  The answer should in some way use the fact that the morphism is étale (or at least flat).

As you can see by the tag, all rings commutative, unital, etc.

Edit: [Why](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaithfullyFlatModule.html) faithfully flat is weaker than faithful + flat.

Edit 2: I resent the voting down of this question without accompanying comments as well as the voting up of the glib and unhelpful answer below.  It's clear that some of you are in the habit of voting on posts based on the poster rather than the content, and I think that is shameful.  There is nothing I can do because none of you has the basic decency to at least leave a comment.  I am completely at your mercy.  You've won.  I hope it's made you very happy.

Edit 3: To answer Emerton's comment, I asked here after:

a.) Reading this [post](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/08/06/algebraic-geometry-without-prime-ideals/#comment-6354) by Jim Borger

b.) Asking my commutative algebra professor in an e-mail

Which led me to believe (perhaps due to a flawed reading of said sources) that this was a harder question than it turned out to be.

Comment: I replaced your $\acute{e}$s with é: the joys of an international keyboard layout! :)

Comment: (As a parenthetical aside, one of the standard definitions of an etale map is one which is [sometimes only locally] of finite type, flat and unramified.  From this definition, etale implies flat takes little work!)  It would be great if finite etale maps were surjective on spectra.  This is not always true: e.g. $\pi_1: \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is finite etale but not faithfully flat.  However, I think it becomes true under further useful hypotheses.  More later, or perhaps this will jog someone else's memory.  

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *"faithful + flat is weaker than being faithfully flat"*? If faithful means that tensoring with S over R never kills a non-zero module, then I think faithfully flat means exactly faithful+flat. Do you mean something else?

Comment: It's an innocent terminology issue.  When HG says that a homomorphism $R \rightarrow S$ of rings is faithful, I think he just means that $S$ is a faithful $R$-module, i.e., that the action does not factor through any proper quotient of $R$.  For a homomorphism of rings, this just means injective. 

Comment: I wasn't aware that there was any other meaning =\.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's also a perfectly reasonable definition of "faithful." Should I add *"tensoring with S over R never kills a non-zero module"* as an answer, or is that your definition?

Comment: That is an answer, yes. 

Comment: Expanding on Pete's comment: if R --> S is injective, finite, and etale, then it is faithfully flat.  (Pf: The map Spec S --> Spec R has dense image, by the injectivity, and has closed image, by finiteness, hence is surjective.)

Comment: Dear Harry, Anton's answer to this question is a textbook answer, available in any number of places (Matsumura certainly, Atiyah--MacDonald it seems based on Anton's answer, surely Eisenbud's tome, ... ).  In the past you've criticised others for posting questions with easily available answers of this type.  Perhaps others are voting down your question for the same reason.  



Comment: I asked here because I thought it was a harder problem based on this [post[(http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/08/06/algebraic-geometry-without-prime-ideals/#comment-6354) by Jim Borger.  

Comment: Dear Harry, In that discussion, Jim is musing about the best way to describe surjectivity of etale maps in functorial terms.  He entertains faithful flatness as one (valid) way.  The concerns are of an aesthetic and philosophical nature (finding the most natural definition from the functorial point of view), not technical.  

Comment: I understand that now... It wasn't clear to me at the time when I made this post.  

Comment: Anyway, with respect to your now voted-up comment, I must add the following:  The only reason that you know of my voting habits is because I leave comments when I vote down posts.  Note that the same courtesy has not been afforded to me.  This is what I am complaining about, not the fact that my question has been voted down.

Comment: Speculating on the motives of such people is worthless.  Please do not speak for them.  They are completely capable of speaking for themselves.  They choose not to.  I'm sick and tired of people doing this.  If this is the kind of place that you want MO to be, so be it.  Then I will engage in the same behavior.  

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of $f:R\to S$ being faithfully flat that I first saw is that $S\otimes_R-$ is exact and faithful (meaning that $S\otimes_R M=0$ implies $M=0$). I'm not sure exactly what your definition of "faithfully flat" is, but it looks like you're happy with "flat and surjective on spectra." You get flatness for free from étaleness, so I'll show that the extra faithfulness condition implies surjectivity on spectra.

Upon tensoring with $S$, $f$ becomes $f\otimes_R id_S:S\cong S\otimes_R R\to S\otimes_R S$, given by $s\mapsto s\otimes 1$. This is injective since it is a section of multiplication $S\otimes_R S\to S$. By flatness of $S$, this shows that $S\otimes_R \ker f=0$, so $\ker f=0$. So I'll identify $R$ with a subring of $S$.

Let $\mathfrak p\subseteq R$ be a prime ideal. We wish to show that there is a prime $\mathfrak q\subseteq S$ such that $\mathfrak q \cap R=\mathfrak p$. Let $K$ be the kernel of the morphism $R/\mathfrak p\to S/\mathfrak p S$ of $R$-modules. Upon tensoring with $S$, this morphism becomes injective (as before, it's a section of the multiplication map $S/\mathfrak p S\otimes_R S/\mathfrak p S\to S/\mathfrak p S$), so by flatness of $S$, we have $S\otimes_R K=0$, so $K=0$. This shows that $\mathfrak p S \cap R=\mathfrak p$ (if the intersection were any larger, $K$ would be non-zero). So $\mathfrak p$ generates a proper ideal in the localization $(R\setminus \mathfrak p)^{-1}S$. Let $\mathfrak q\subseteq (R\setminus \mathfrak p)^{-1}S$ be a maximal ideal containing $\mathfrak p$. This corresponds to some prime ideal $\mathfrak q$ (slight abuse of notation to use the same letter) of $S$ which contains $\mathfrak p$ but does not intersect $R\setminus \mathfrak p$, so $\mathfrak q\cap R=\mathfrak p$.

See also exercise 16 of Chapter 3 of Atiyah-Macdonald.

Comment: I assume that you mean that $f:R\to S$ is _faithful_.

Comment: Also, faithful (in your sense) + flat = faithfully flat = surjective on spectra. Any map that is surjective on spectra is automatically faithfully flat. 

Comment: Surjective on spectra *does not* imply faithfully flat; you also need flatness. For example, if p⊂R is a prime, then R → R/p⊕R_p is surjective on spectra, but not flat.

Comment: Not what wikipedia says, at least: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faithfully_flat  Although it could be in error.

Comment: No, the wikipedia page is correct, though awkwardly worded: *"...it makes sense to ask if S is flat over R. If this is the case, then S is faithfully flat over R if and only if..."*. They are already assuming S is flat over R.

Comment: I didn't define flatness, but you're right that the definition of flatness is that the functor I noted should be exact. You get this for free from étaleness. The additional condition I'm imposing is that the functor is *also* faithful.

Comment: The first sentence of your post is not what you'd intended to type (hence what I said about the typo and also my first comment.)

Comment: Ah, I see it; I forgot the word "faithful." I've added it now. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that f becomes an isomorphism upon tensoring with S?
Rather, doesn't it become a section to the ``diagonal'' S\otimes_R S \to  S?   Nevertheless, it is thus injective, and thus I = 0, as claimed.

Comment: @Emerton: you're right. I'll fix that now. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Anton, probably the same edit is required in the next paragraph,
when you reduce module primes.

Comment: It looks like I was fixing that just as you were writing the comment. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the overzealousness!

Comment: Sorry, my example in an earlier comment is confused. Take a prime number p∈ℤ, then ℤ → ℤ/p ⊕ ℤ[p^{-1}] is surjective on spectra but not flat.

Comment: Even better, k[ε]/(ε²) → k is surjective on spectra but not flat.

Answer (score 6):

so yeah, look, i was trying to be funny & also trying to highlight the absurdly haughty nature of the caveats in the question.  to be serious i would say that if F is etale then it is faithfully flat iff it is surjective on separably-closed field valued points, but also remark that the same is true with "etale" replaced by "smooth", so i guess i'm not using the full strength of the etale condition.

Comment: @Dustin: The only reason I included those caveats is because people sometimes actually post answers like that one if you've left out some conditions.  